# send and receive SMS over PSTN

Tags: sms, telephony

I want to know how to send and receive `SMS` via PC modem over `PSTN`? Is there any application to do this for me or what's the protocol of this process?

Comment: Closest you would get is an email to SMS gateway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an operator who supports fixed line SMS and you need a modem that can send the SMS such as:

http://www.ntstelecom.co.uk/SMSmodem.htm

An application which can send SMS's using a GSM modem and AT commands will probably be able to use the above, in place of the GSM modem, to send the SMS over the PSTN.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to send SMS via your PC try [Google Voice](http://www.google.com/googlevoice/about.html). It is free and it lets you send and receive SMS from a web browser.